# Book of shaders exercises

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader

I am spending  this winter holidays trying to learn something about shaders, I am stuck with this couple exercise:

```
y = sin(x);
```

Try the following exercises and notice what happens:

- Add time (u_time) to x before computing the sin. Internalize that motion along
  x.

how do I implement it?

Comment: [The book of shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/) has nothing to do with three.js. If you to learn WebGL consider [these articles](https://webglfundamentals.org)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need 2 uniform variables, the resolution of the viewport (`u_resolution`) and the time (`u_time`) in seconds:

```c
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform float u_time;
```

`x` can be get by the x coordinate of the fragment. Map the x coordinate to the range [0, 2*PI]:

```c
vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
float x = st.x * 2.0 * 3.141529;
```

Calculate `y`. [`sin`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/sin.xhtml) is the [Sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine) function:

```c
float y = sin(x + u_time);
```

Set the color channels of the fragment by `y`. `y` has to be mapped from the range [-1, 1], to [0, 1]:

```c
gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(y*0.5+0.5), 1.0);
```

The result is a sine gradient, moving from the right to the left:

```js
var container, camera, scene, renderer, uniforms;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
    camera = new THREE.Camera();
    camera.position.z = 1;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2, 2 );

    uniforms = {
        u_time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
        u_resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() }
    };

    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
    } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    (window.onresize = function() {
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        uniforms.u_resolution.value.x = renderer.domElement.width;
        uniforms.u_resolution.value.y = renderer.domElement.height;
    })();
}

function animate(delta_ms) {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    uniforms.u_time.value = delta_ms / 1000.0;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```html
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform float u_time;

void main() {
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;

    float x = st.x * 2.0 * 3.141529;
    float y = sin(x + u_time);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(y*0.5+0.5), 1.0);
}
</script>

<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be something like this:

```
y = sin(u_time + x);
```

You should see the sin wave moving along the x axis.

Explanation:
u_time is the time in seconds since the shader started.  Using this variable, we can add it to the x value before calculating sin, which will give the effect of the wave moving along the x axis.

To implement it, you can change the text just under the graph.[image]

Comment: An explanation of the answer would likely be more helpful to someone learning the subject...

Comment: I think he want to know where to get `x` from and what to do with `y`.